# How to redo renaming interfaces with 70-persistent-net.rules?

Tags: network-interface, udev, interface

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and renamed the interfaces and want to redo this renaming. I don't want to use the `70-persistent-net.rules` for the back renaming.

I delete the content and removed the file with reboots, but it doesn't help.

I checked `/lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules`, but there is nothing relevant. I also have no `*-persistent-net-generator.rules` file. And the path `/etc/systemd/network/` is also empty.

This is the content of `01-network-manager-all.yaml`.

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Different Linux distributions handle NIC renaming in different ways. In very old RedHat and relatives, you might use `HWADDR=` in NIC configuration files; in slightly less old systems there might be something like `/lib/udev/rules.d/*-persistent-net-generator.rules` that will auto-generate `70-persistent-net.rules`; newer distributions using `systemd` might use `*.link` files in directory `/etc/systemd/network/` to assign names to NICs. Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I use ubuntu. I don't have a ``-persistent-net-generator.rules`` file and no link files at ``/etc/systemd/network/``.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Starting from Ubuntu 17.10 ("Artful"), it has been using `netplan`, so the main network configuration will come from one or more `*.yaml` files in directories `/etc/netplan/`, `/lib/netplan/` and/or `/run/netplan/`.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04. I updated my post.